# use make to recompile my program by .c files

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a makefile that doesn't recompile my program if I delete my object files...because my .c files are up to date, how can I do this?

I try to do this but it doesn't work

```
SRC = main.c file.c file1.c

OBJ = $(SRC:c=o)

%.o: %.c 
    gcc -c $< -o $@

name = program

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(SRC) ; $(OBJ)
    gcc $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)
```

Comment: Well, it is possible if you mark your object files as "temporary" or "intermediate" or so. I have done so, and seen it with other projects, to the extend that such intermediate files are automatically removed after the build. Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to provide an example. -- OT: `name = program` should be  `NAME = program`.

Comment: You probably want to use secondary targets.   see [Chained Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank! To solve my problem i'm must add special target .INTERMEDIATE or .SECONDARY like this:
More details on this issue can be found at the link [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules%5D) provided by Henry.

```
SRC = main.c file.c file1.c

OBJ = $(SRC:c=o)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

NAME = program

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(SRC) ; $(OBJ)
    gcc $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

.SECONDARY: $(OBJ)
```

Comment: The problem with using INTERMEDIATE is that these are not actually intermediate files.  A true intermediate file is one that is not needed to create the target.  The prototypical example is a static library: a static library is an archive of .o files and you can replace a single .o file in an existing library without having all the other .o files.  An executable is not like that: yes, if your executable is up to date WRT _all_ your source files you don't need the objects.  But as soon as ANY source file is newer, now you need ALL the object files in order to re-link.

Comment: That's why people typically don't bother with trying to special-case .o files for binaries: it doesn't really buy you anything to delete them.  You'll just end up recompiling them all again anyway which is LESS efficient.  Only in the most unique situations does it make sense to delete these types of object files.  Maybe you should consider converting your object files into a static library and linking that, if you really want to proceed down this path.

Comment: but using SECONDARY doesn't remove my .o files and gives me the required result. I'm listen you, i think i can create lib and use `ar s` to update that than it necessary.

Comment: I'm saying there's a good reason your required result is not something anyone does: it doesn't work.  Try it: run `make` so everything is up to date and the `.o` files are intermediate so make removes them.  Now, modify one of the `.c` files then run `make`.  It will fail, because the program can't be linked unless ALL the object files exist.

Comment: Yes, you could create a static library and replace objects in it (using `ar r` not `ar s`).  make has special support for static libraries: it can look inside them and examine the timestamps on the individual object files in that archive.  But, you haven't explained WHY you want to do this.  If the goal is to save disk space this won't help: the object files still are there, and they take up just as much disk space, they're just inside one archive file instead of individual .o files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is basically impossible.

To create the binary, you need the object files. To create the object files you need the source files.

The binary is up to date if it is newer than the up to date object files. And the object files are up to date if they are newer than the source files.

There is no direct route from the binary to the source files. Deleting the object files will *always* rebuild your source code.

Update: It is possible (as pointed below), but not easy. And IMHO the makefile complexity added is not worth it. Just keep the object files. Instead change the makefile to put you object files in a separate directory away from the source code.

Comment: If the final linked object (`program`) in this case is newer than all the .c files, the .o files would not be required -- and make does support this -- see [Chained Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) for information.

Comment: But, if my .c files are older than program i'm not need recompile my program

Comment: Yes -- but without using `.SECONDARY` for example, make would rebuild program if any of the .o's are missing.   Declaring the .o files as `.SECONDARY` will let make know it does not need to rebuild program if the dependencies of the .o files are up to date, but the .o file itself is missing.  --- read the link I posted, it has lots of useful information on what you're trying to do.